# Android Realm Database not updating Record

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, realm

I am new to Android Development i am trying to sort item position in `Recyclerview` i am useing Realm Database and my data-set for Adapter is `RealmResults<ShoppingList>`

here is my `Adapter` please take look my `moveItemDown` and `updateItemPosition` method i m trying to update item position in updateItemPosition Method but it's not working. i also attached my view below the adapter

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private RealmResults<ShoppingList> dataList;
    private Realm mRealm;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public RecyclerAdapter(Context context, RealmResults<ShoppingList> data, Realm reamDatabaseInstence){
        this.dataList = data;
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        mRealm = reamDatabaseInstence;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Log.i("Recycler", "onCreateViewHolder");

        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.shopping_list_item, parent,false);
        MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Log.i("Recycler", "onBindViewHolder " + position);

        ShoppingList currentItem = dataList.get(position);
        holder.setData(currentItem, position);
        holder.setListener();
    }

    public void moveItemDown(int position){
        if( position == (dataList.size()-1) ) { return; }
        int oi = position;
        int ni = position+1;
        updateItemPosition(oi, ni);
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    public void moveItemUp(int position){
        // Need to implement after down sort work
    }

    private void updateItemPosition(final int pos, final int new_pos){
        mRealm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                ShoppingList old_item = realm.where(ShoppingList.class)
                        .equalTo("position", pos)
                        .findFirst();
                old_item.setPosition(new_pos);
                Log.d("UpdateData: ",old_item.getTitle()+" "+old_item.getPosition());

                ShoppingList new_item = realm.where(ShoppingList.class)
                        .equalTo("position", new_pos)
                        .findFirst();
                new_item.setPosition(pos);
                Log.d("UpdateData: ",new_item.getTitle()+" "+new_item.getPosition());

            }
        });
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        TextView title;
        ImageButton up, down;
        ImageView image;
        int position;
        ShoppingList current;

        MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.shopping_card_view_title);
            image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.shopping_card_view_image);
            up = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.shopping_card_view_up_btn);
            down = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.shopping_card_view_down_btn);
        }

        void setData(ShoppingList i, int position) {
            title.setText( i.getTitle() );
            image.setImageResource(i.getImageId());
            this.position = position;
            this.current = i;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()){
                case R.id.shopping_card_view_up_btn:
                    moveItemUp(position);
                    break;
                case R.id.shopping_card_view_down_btn:
                    moveItemDown(position);
                    break;
            }
        }

        void setListener() {
            up.setOnClickListener(MyViewHolder.this);
            down.setOnClickListener(MyViewHolder.this);
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's late reply by it would help to you and this is the combination of both answer **`EpicPandaForce`** give a great example to work with `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter` and make your Recyclerview automated.

**Second Option**
this is to use **`UNIQUE ID FIELD`** in order to make changes in list item.

**Here is the problem happening in you Code**
Basically when you get an item by it's position for instance `position=1;` and you updated to position 2 right? notice now you have two item with same `position = 2` and now when you try to get first item with `position = 2` Realm return the same item that you updated from position 1 to 2 now what happening here you updated dated position back to `position=1`;

`taman neupane` give you good idea but he is not describe much.

Please **TRY THIS**

```
private void updateItemPosition(final int pos, final int new_pos){

    final String current_item_id = dataList.get(pos).get_id();
    final String new_item_id = dataList.get(new_pos).get_id();

    mRealm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            // Try to find the result with unique id replace this .equalTo("Your Unique ID Field name", current_item_id)
            ShoppingList old_item = realm.where(ShoppingList.class).equalTo("position", pos).findFirst();

            old_item.setPosition(new_pos);
            // Also here Try to find the result with unique id replace this .equalTo("Your Unique ID Field name", new_item_id)
            ShoppingList new_item = realm.where(ShoppingList.class).equalTo("position", new_pos).findFirst();

            new_item.setPosition(pos);
            //new you can tell you adapter about the changes in dataset.
            notifyItemMoved(pos, new_pos);
            notifyItemRangeChanged(pos, dataList.getSize());
        }
    });
}
```

and then update your both function with that

```
public void moveItemDown(int position){
    if( position == (dataList.size()-1) ) { return; }
    int oi = position;
    int ni = position+1;
    updateItemPosition(oi, ni);
}

public void moveItemUp(int position){
    if( position == 0 ) { return; }
    int oi = position;
    int ni = position-1;
    updateItemPosition(ni, oi);
}
```

And That's it.
**If anyone want to modify my explanation i will appreciate because i am not good in english.**

Happy Coding.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your explanation let me try your solution.

Comment: Perfect :) Thank you so much for you great explanation and code. it's working now,

Answer (score 1):

To get automatic updates, you should use `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter` from https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<ShoppingList, RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder> { // <-- !
    private Realm mRealm;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public RecyclerAdapter(Context context, RealmResults<ShoppingList> data, Realm realm){
        super(data, true);
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        mRealm = realm;
    }
```

and replace `dataList` with `getData()`

Answer (score 0):

I think your ShoppingList item has unique id for all. Just make id field primary and use realmInsertorUpdate feature . You don't have to check for any thing else. If the id is available it will update the database and if id is not available it will just insert.